# Cambio masivo de propiedad de un campo

Tags: sql-server

me gustaría hacer una consulta o procedimiento que me buscara en una base de datos todos los campos con un nombre concreto y si el tamaño de el campo fuera menor a **N**, le estableciera un nuevo valor.
Es decir, establecer todos los campos llamados `articulo` de una base de datos de `Varchar(8)` a `Varchar(15)`. 
¿Alguien me puede guiar en como hacerlo?
Muchas gracias.

Es MSSQL Server, perdon por no especificarlo, creí que con Transact-sql en las etiquetas era suficiente, lo siento.

Comment: en todas las bases de datos que he visto hay una tabla que guarda el schema, navega un poco por tu estructura a ver si lo encuentras y con bucles lo consigues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes una propuesta básica, que sirve de solución a lo que pides y que puedes modificar según convenga o bien poner en un procedimiento pasando parámetros.

Creamos un cursor que mediante las tablas de sistema `sys.objects`, `sys.columns`, `sys.schemas` y `sys.types` y el `WHERE` nos devuelven la lista de campos coincidentes y sus propiedades (esquema, nombre de la tabla, nombre del campo y tipo). En este caso solo las columnas cuyo nombre es 'articulo'.

Para cada una de ellas monta un string con la sentencia `ALTER` y la ejecuta. Cada una de ellas seria del tipo:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Articulos] ALTER COLUMN [Articulo] VARCHAR (15)
```

Solo toma tablas de usuario (`where a.type='u'`). Solo toma campos del tipo `varchar` y `nvarchar`, cuya longitud sea 8 y lo transforma en longitud 15.

```
declare @schema varchar(250)
declare @Tabla varchar(250)
declare @Campo varchar(250)
declare @tipo varchar(20)
DECLARE prod_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
select d.name, a.name, b.name, c.name
from sys.objects a
inner join sys.columns b on a.object_id = b.object_id 
inner join sys.systypes c on b.system_type_id = c.xtype
inner join sys.schemas d on a.schema_id = d.schema_id 
where a.type='u'
and c.name in ('varchar', 'nvarchar')
and b.name = 'articulo'
and b.max_length = 8

OPEN prod_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM prod_cursor 
INTO @schema, @Tabla, @Campo, @tipo

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    declare @sql varchar(500)
    set @sql = 'ALTER TABLE [' +  @schema + '].[' + @Tabla + '] ALTER COLUMN [ ' + @Campo + '] ' + @tipo + ' (15)'
    exec(@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM prod_cursor 
    INTO @schema, @Tabla, @Campo, @tipo
END 
CLOSE prod_cursor
DEALLOCATE prod_cursor
```

**EDIT**
Cuando se encuentre algún campo asociado a un Constraint dará error. Este Constraint puede ser de la misma tabla o bien de otra tabla que haga referencia a la que se está modificando. Por ello puedes desactivar temporalmente estas restricciones mediante

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

para luego volver a activarlas

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Comment: cursores es mala práctica, son lentos y bloquean las tablas, hay métodos para sustituir los por bucles

Comment: Entiendo que son mala practica para producción, pero para administración ¿qué problema hay?

Comment: Es posible que sys.columns no contenga ninguna de las columnas de la base de datos que inteno modificar ?

Comment: No es posible, todas las columnas están en `sys.columns`. Reduce la consulta para ver lo que ocurre: `select *
from sys.objects a
inner join sys.columns b on a.object_id = b.object_id WHERE a.name='Nombretabla'`

Comment: Si, cierto. Ya está, aunque no va a ser tan fácil como pensaba ya que cuando se encuentra algún campo ARTICULO asociado a un constraint falla. Debería, eliminar el constraint, hacer el ALTER y volver a construir el constaint y sinceramente, no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @carallot, he editado la respuesta con la posibilidad de evitar las constraint

Comment: @Carallot, no debes editar las respuestas, solo queda o bien otra pregunta o los comentarios. ¿En que línea tienes el error del índice? ¿en el rebuild?

Comment: Pido disculpas, no tengo claro si puedo pegar código en un comentario.Creo que el error me lo da al hacer el `ALTER` para modificar el tamaño del campo.

Comment: @roger-torné es posible que el error sea debido a que es una primary key ? si es así ¿ como puedo sortearlas ?

Comment: ¿primary key un campo `char` con el nombre descriptivo de un artículo? Entonces tenéis un problema mayor: de diseño. En cuanquier cado una primary key no puede desactivarse. Debe quitarse y luego ponerse.

Comment: La base de datos no es mía, pero así es, solo que no hace referencia al nombre descriptivo si no al código de articulo de la tabla maestra `articulos`. ¿Entonces no puedo hacer lo que quería no?